# QGIS measure tool: How to edit default SR on ellipsoidal method?

Tags: qgis, measurements

When I use the measure tool on QGIS 3.22, about ellipsoidic method it says: "Coordinates has been transphormed in the choosen ellipsoid (EPSG: 7030)": this sounds strange because all CRS settings in my project are setted in EPSG: 32632.

I tried to check project and Measure tool settings options, but it looks that there are no way to customize the measure tool settings.

[image: QGIS measure tool sr]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`EPSG:7030`](https://epsg.io/7030-ellipsoid) is the parametric definition of the *reference ellipsoid* within the [WGS84 geodetic reference system](https://epsg.io/4326).

Nothing wrong here.